# No "et al." truncation for pieces with more than 3 authors (natbib)

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, apacite

```
@article{karki2017fabrication,
Author = {Karki, Bhishma and Nakarmi, Jeevan Jyoti and Singh, Rhiddi Bir and Banerjee, Manish},
Journal = {Advanced Materials Proceedings},
Number = {9},
Pages = {575-580},
Publisher = {VBRI},
Title = {Fabrication of {Au}:{ZnO} thin films by a solution assisted route for application in photoelectrocatalytic degradation of methylene blue (MB)},
Volume = {2},
Year = {2017}}
```

This is my bibliography for natbib, but even though, such settings work for other list when the authors are more than 3, I am not getting `Karki et al.` when I use `\citep{karki2017fabrication}`. Instead, I am getting `(Karki, Nakarmi, Singh, & Banerjee, 2017)`. I don't know what's the issue? Thanks

Comment: If and how name lists are truncated in citations will depend on the bibliography style you use. We can only help you if you share with us what bibliography/citation packages you load (you mention `natbib`, so you probably load only that) and which bibliography style you use (`\bibliographystyle`) ideally in a fully compilable example document (a so-called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864).

Comment: Bibliography style is apacite

Comment: `apacite` implements the citation and bibliography style required by the 6th ed. of the APA manual. One property of that citation style is that works with 3 to 5 authors (I think, the numbers might be slightly different) are cited in full the first time and will only be abbreviated to "First et al." on subsequent citations. That is what `apacite` implements. If you don't want that behaviour I suggest you use a different style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The piece you're citing has four authors. What you're experiencing -- the full list of authors being shown in the citation call-out, the first time a piece with between 3 and 5 authors is cited -- is a deliberate design feature of the `apacite` bibliography style. Only in subsequent citation call-outs to such an entry is the familiar "et al" truncation scheme employed.

For pieces with 6 or more authors or editors, the `apacite` bib style truncates the author list in the citation call-out the very first time a piece is cited.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@article{karki2017fabrication,
Author = {Karki, Bhishma and Nakarmi, Jeevan Jyoti and 
          Singh, Rhiddi Bir and Banerjee, Manish},
Title  = {Fabrication of {Au}:{ZnO} thin films by a solution 
          assisted route for application in 
          photoelectrocatalytic degradation of 
          methylene blue ({MB})},
Journal= {Advanced Materials Proceedings},
Year   = {2017},
Volume = {2},
Number = {9},
Pages  = {575--580},
Publisher = {VBRI},
}
@misc{test,
 author = "A and B and C and D and E and F and G",
 title  = "Thoughts",
 year   = 3001,
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optional

\begin{document}
\citep{karki2017fabrication}, \citep{karki2017fabrication}

\citep{test}, \citep{test}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```